# Why is git 'dim' color option not working?

Tags: git, bash, terminal

I am configuring git's usage of color, however the attribute 'dim' doesn't have a visible effect.
According to [the specification](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config):

> The colors accepted are normal, black, red, green, yellow, blue, magenta, cyan and white; the attributes are bold, dim, ul, blink and reverse. The first color given is the foreground; the second is the background. The position of the attribute, if any, doesn't matter.

All the other attributes work and the chosen color does not seem to be related to the problem.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9074343/1937646) has a comment from a person with the same problem, but with no proposed solution.

Is this a git problem? A terminal problem (I am using konsole and bash on linux)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is unrelated to git; Konsole simply doesn't interpret the dim attribute; as you can try yourself with

```
printf '\033[38;5;1mnormal \033[02;38;5;1mdim \033[01;38;5;1mbold'
```

[image: dim demo in konsole]

Comment: and how can I emulate the effect or add support for it?